# How to initialize a vector using sregex_token_iterator objects

Tags: c++, c++17

In this code I convert a comma separated sting into `sregex_token_iterator` objects.

But when I try to initialize a vector using the `sregex_token_iterator` objects, I get **static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range** error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string uinput = "1,2, 3";
  const regex regex(R"(\s*,\s*)");
  sregex_token_iterator beg(uinput.begin(), uinput.end(), regex, -1), end;
  for_each(beg, end, [](auto& token) { cout << token << '\n'; }); // just for checks
  vector<int> v(beg, end); // Gives this error:
  // static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
}
```

How to  initialize a vector properly using `sregex_token_iterator` objects? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Value type of `std::sregex_token_iterator` is `std::sub_match`. This cannot be implicitly converted to `int`, since there is no corresponding cast operator.

However, `std::sub_match` has a [string-cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match/str). You can, therefore, construct a `std::vector<std::string>` this way:

```
std::vector<std::string> v(beg, end);
```

If you need integers, you can then convert to a vector of `int`s manually, or, write a custom *iterator adaptor* that would convert strings to integers on-the-fly.